# How can I list Terraform resources with their IDs

Tags: terraform

I want to move some Terraform resources from one repository to another. I reckon the simplest way to do that would be `terraform import` in one repository and `terraform rm` in the other.

With `terraform state list` I can get a list of resources, but without their ID. I thought I can combine that output with `terraform state show` but it's very slow and I have to parse out the ID from the HCL. Unfortunately there is no JSON output.

With `terraform show -json` I can get the whole state in JSON format, but there can be a lot of nesting of modules, so parsing that wouldn't be trivial either.

Are there any other options?

Edit 1:

`terraform show -json` for the relatively small repository I am working on gives me 2000 lines (too much to be sure of the format) starting with:

```
{
    "format_version": "0.1",
    "terraform_version": "0.14.9",
    "values": {
        "root_module": {
            "child_modules": [
                {
                    "address": "module.cloudtrail",
                    "child_modules": [
                        {
                            "address": "module.cloudtrail.module.cloudtrail_bucket",
                            "resources": [
                                {
```

I think there is at least one more level of nesting of `child_modules`. I think resources can be on every level. It's possible to get the list from that, but I don't think it's trivial.

Comment: Can you shown an example of the output from `terraform show -json` to get an idea why its non-trival?

Comment: You could use `jq` to process the json and get the values you require.

Comment: I started off with `jq` and then I saw that I don't get a flat list, but all this nesting.

Comment: You have to provide full example json and jq command you tried, and what you got and what do you want to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realised that I kind of get what I want every time I do a `terraform plan`. But I don't want the plan, so I can do `terraform refresh | sed s'|: Refreshing state... \[id=| |' | sed s'|\]$||'`. It's a bit slow, but I get a list of resources with their ID.

I can even add `sed s'|^|terraform import |' > import.sh` and import all the resources (or a part of them after an edit) with `bash import.sh`

Comment: Building on your solution, I came up with the following:

`terraform refresh -no-color | sed -E s'|: Refreshing state... \[id=(.*)\]| \1|' | sed s'|^|terraform import |' > import.sh`

Also, if you use a -var-file when applying, don't forget to use it on the `terraform refresh` - otherwise it will appear to hang as it sits there waiting for input!